# A request word of an adjective for "a person who gets satisfied quickly"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request, word-meaning

> Suppose my mom buys my sister some clothes in a clothing shop.
> Actually, my sister doesn't like the clothes, but she doesn't say
> anything and just urges us to go home.

I assume that my sister gets satisfied quickly regardless of whether she likes the clothes or not. If I want to describe my sister using an adjective, what would it be?

A satisfied woman? I don't think so. To me, it sounds like she is really satisfied with the clothes. What is it? Also, a woman who gets satisfied quickly is rather mouthful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One might say that such a person is "easily pleased". Or "easily satisfied". Onme mighjt say that such a person is "compliant" or "complaisant".

But none of those exactly captures the aspect that your longer description does. To fully and clearly convey your meaning, I can't think of any one-word adjective or other term. The longer description is probably better, at least the first tiem you mention this concept. Then you could use it to define for your purposes one of the tems above, and then use the shorter term so the listener or reader will better understand your meaning.

Also, be careful with using the term "satisfied". It has a sexual sense that might easily spring to the mind(s) of your audience even when it is not intendeds and not appropriate.